# kontx media player to play embed videos

Tags: javascript, yahoo, yahoo-widgets

I have been working on Yahoo connected TV application development.

The primary goal of the app is to play embedded videos from various sources like YouTube and Dailymotion. I'm using the Yahoo Widgets framework which provides media player control.

The problem with this player is that it is not playing videos when I pass embed URL to it.

Is it possible to play embed videos using this player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo Connected TV's cannot play "embedded" url's. The video URL must point to a video encoded as mp4/h.264. For more information on the media player, see this documentation: https://developer.yahoo.com/connectedtv/kontxapiref/YCTV_KONTX_Media_Player.html